# Downloading PDB file for machine not connected to the internet

Tags: debugging, windbg, pdb-files

For deubgging some process I will need to download the PDB files for some operating system dll files (OLE32, NTDLL, etc.)

That server is not connected to the internet.

I know the following method to get the PDB.

1. Get full dump of the process
2. Copy the dump to another machine where internet connection is available
3. Use .reload to download the PDB files
4. Copy the PDB files from the local PDB store

Is there any thing more simple or do I have to go through the dumping process?

Thanks
Saar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Symbol packages](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/symbolpkg.mspx) are available for download from Microsoft. You can download and install the synbol package, and then point WinDbg to look where they were installed.

The installers are *not* web-based, so you can just download those you need once and keep them on a USB memory drive or external hard drive.